# How to obtain Fastly keys on Magento Cloud?

Tags: magento2, magento2-cloud, fastly

I have a Magento Cloud installation and Fastly is configured out-of-the-box. Although, I need to use the Fastly API to trigger a Curl command using the API key.

How is it possible to get the API key from my Fastly setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be able to find your token in a file directly on your server, you can access it on your server via SSH by opening the file:

```
/mnt/shared/fastly_tokens.txt
```